# Backfill values based on other column values

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, greenplum

What i have

```
customerid   status_1 status_2 status_3 status_4 status_5

Ax             1         0         0        0        0
Bx             0         0         1        0        0
Cx             0         0         0        0        1
Dx             0         0         0        1        0
Ex             0         1         0        0        0
```

I want to backfill the values in the columns based on other column value

1. if status_1 =1 then status_2, status_3, status_4 and status_5 should be 0.
2. if status_2 =1 then status_1 should be 1, and status_3, status_4 and status_5 should be 0.
3. if status_3 =1 then status_1 & status 2 should be 1, and status_4 and status_5 should be 0.
4. if status_4 =1 then status_1, status 2 & status 5 should be 1, and status_3 should be 0.
5. if status_5 =1 then status_1, status_2, status_3 & status_4 should be 1.

Output looks like below

```
 customerid   status_1 status_2 status_3 status_4 status_5

Ax         1         0         0        0        0
Bx         1         1         1        0        0
Cx         1         1         1        1        1
Dx         1         1         0        1        1
Ex         1         1         0        0        0
```

Comment: what if a row has more than one status with 1?

Comment: There will be 1 for only any of the one status.i wont be having more than 1 column having status 1

Comment: In your question, the scenario 4) if status_4 =1 then status_1,status 2 & status 5 should be 1, and status_3 should be 0 looks different than the other scenarios. Why is that? I am able to understand the pattern due to that.

Comment: status_4 =1 is an exception scenario where status_1,status 2 & status 5 should be 1 and status_3 is 0

Comment: @user8545255 so based on your conditions status_1 is always 1?

Comment: exactly..status_1 is always 1

Comment: Are you using Postgres or Greenplum? Do not add tags for DBMS not involved

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select customer_id,
    case when status_5 = 1 or status_4 = 1 or status_3 = 1 or status_2 = 1 or status_1 = 1 then 1 else 0 end as status_1,
    case when status_5 = 1 or status_4 = 1 or status_3 = 1 or status_2 = 1 then 1 else 0 end as status_2,
    case when status_5 = 1 or status_3 = 1 then 1 else 0 end as status_3,
    case when status_5 = 1 or status_4 = 1 then 1 else 0 end as status_4,
    case when status_5 = 1 or status_4 = 1 then 1 else 0 end as status_5
from your_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the **BACKFILL** query will produce the desired result.

Also the following query requires less changes when add new columns ex.status6,status7,status8,...

The "add" and "or" in select is added when column requires **EXCEPTIONS** like status_4

And since status_1 is always 1 in your case you can replace (1<=pos.one) with 1

```
    with your_table(customerid,status_1,status_2,status_3,status_4,status_5) as (
    select *
    from (
      values
        ('AX',1,0,0,0,0),
        ('BX',0,0,1,0,0),
        ('CX',0,0,0,0,1),
        ('DX',0,0,0,1,0),
        ('EX',0,1,0,0,0)
     ) t
    )
    select
     customerid,
     (1<=pos.one)::int as status1,
     (2<=pos.one)::int as status2,
     (3<=pos.one and pos.one!=4)::int as status3,
     (4<=pos.one)::int as status4,
     (5<=pos.one or pos.one=4)::int as status5
    from
    your_table t,
    lateral
    (
     select position('1' in t.status_1::text||t.status_2||t.status_3||t.status_4||t.status_5) as one
    ) pos
```